# Passing options to mocha when running from npm

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, npm, mocha.js, nyc

I am setting up nyc/mocha for my project. I want to pass `--exit` option to mocha when running mocha with/without nyc.

Here's my packages.json:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node ./app",
    "test": "./node_modules/.bin/mocha --exit",
    "test-with-coverage": "nyc --reporter=html mocha --reporter mochawesome --exit",
    "apidoc": "apidoc -i routes/ -o apidocs/"
  }
```

But this throws invalid option error when I run npm test or npm run test-with-coverage.

How do you pass any options to mocha from npm?

Comment: no so sure, but isnt there to times `--` in your command (after html mocha)

Comment: Even after removing `--` it doesn't work.

Comment: You did try exaclty this `nyc --reporter=html mocha -- --reporter mochawesome` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only reason I can see for having the problem with the code you show is that `--exit` was added in [Mocha 4.0.0](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#400--2017-10-02) and you happen to be using an older version.